# Order by rating not works in wp_query

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to sort my products by rating in a wp_query loop:

this is my code:

```
switch($ordering){
    case 'default':
        $meta_key = '';
        $order = 'asc';
        $orderby = 'menu_order title';
        break;
    case 'popularity':
        $meta_key = '';
        $order = 'desc';
        $orderby = 'total_sales';
        break;
    case 'low_to_high':
        $meta_key = '_price';
        $order = 'asc';
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
        break;
    case 'high_to_low':
        $meta_key = '_price';
        $order = 'desc';
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
        break;
    case 'newness':
        $meta_key = '';
        $order = 'desc';
        $orderby = 'date';
        break;
    case 'rating':
        $meta_key = '';
        $order = 'desc';
        $orderby = 'rating';
        break;
}

$args_products_sorting = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'meta_key' => $meta_key
);
```

Where is the error ?

If i set in url `?orderby=rating` it works correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is $meta_key for case 'rating' empty?

Comment: because the meta key is not `rating` , use `_wc_average_rating` instead

Answer (score 10):

You should use `'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num'` and `'meta_key'  => 'rating'` as specified by the WordPress Codec. Using `meta_value_num` with the assumption your ratings are numeric values

Reference: [Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: UPDATE : today is year 2020 . if the solution above didn't work , try using 
`_wc_average_rating`  as the meta_key. 


So instead of  `'meta_key' => 'rating'`


try using


`'meta_key' => '_wc_average_rating'`

Answer (score 5):

Seems like there are a lot of meta keys you can order by ([here](https://wedevs.com/support/topic/meta-keys-for-attributes/#post-4742) is a list I’ve found). However I couldn’t find anything rating related. I searched for `rating` in the WooCommerce source code and found this line: [includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1087](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1087)

So here is what finally worked for me in the context of using the WooCommerce PHP REST API client:

```
function getProducts(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    global $wc_api_client;

    $category = $request->get_param('category');
    // $filters = $request->get_param('filters');
    $orderby = $request->get_param('orderby');

    $args = null;

    $wc_query = new WC_Query();
    switch ( $orderby ) {
        case 'date':
            $args = array(
                'filter[limit]' => 6,
                'filter[category]' => $category,
                'filter[orderby]' => 'date',
                'filter[order]' => 'DESC'
            );
            break;
        case 'price':
            $args = array(
                'filter[limit]' => 6,
                'filter[category]' => $category,
                'filter[orderby]' => 'meta_value_num',
                'filter[order]' => 'ASC',
                'filter[orderby_meta_key]' => '_price'
            );
            break;
        case 'price-desc':
            $args = array(
                'filter[limit]' => 6,
                'filter[category]' => $category,
                'filter[orderby]' => 'meta_value_num',
                'filter[order]' => 'DESC',
                'filter[orderby_meta_key]' => '_price'
            );
            break;
        case 'popularity':
            $args = array(
                'filter[limit]' => 6,
                'filter[category]' => $category,
                'filter[orderby]' => 'meta_value_num',
                'filter[order]' => 'DESC',
                'filter[orderby_meta_key]' => 'total_sales'
            );
            break;
        case 'rating':
            $args = array(
                'filter[limit]' => 6,
                'filter[category]' => $category,
                'filter[orderby]' => 'meta_value_num',
                'filter[order]' => 'DESC',
                'filter[orderby_meta_key]' => '_wc_average_rating'
            );
            break;
        default:
            $args = array(
                'filter[limit]' => 6,
                'filter[category]' => $category
            );
    }

    try {
        $raw = $wc_api_client->products->get('', $args);
        return $raw['products'];
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return new WP_Error('no_products', 'Couldn’t find any products', array('status' => 404));
    }
}
```

Comment: Explaining what you do in your answers is not just the nice thing to do, it is considered mandatory for an answer to be considered as good. So please, add an explanation about the context and why this works - thanks.

Comment: @ialocin A comment would have been enough (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers). I added some more info.

Comment: I down vote answers not meeting quality standards to give a bigger incentive to better them - that is just it and I always leave a comment with it. And to be honest, I don't care if other people behave differently. Another thing, what about those »filter[---]« parameters, where do they come from?

Comment: @ialocin I've added some more context. I cannot add more links, don’t have enought “internet points” since I’ve spent all of them for the bounty...

Comment: See, we are getting there :) thanks. I'd guess it is ok like this, because with the information, everybody themselves can search it.

Answer (score 1):

I used something like that and it works

```
switch ($order_by){
                case 'price':
                    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
                    $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
                    $args['order'] = 'asc';
                    break;

                case 'price-desc':
                    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
                    $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
                    $args['order'] = 'desc';
                    break;

                case 'rating':
                    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
                    $args['meta_key'] = '_wc_average_rating';
                    $args['order'] = 'desc';
                    break;

                case 'popularity':
                    $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
                    $args['meta_key'] = 'total_sales';
                    $args['order'] = 'desc';
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this . Use WC_Shortcode_Products to generate the wc loop with sort parameters were used at default wc shop page

```
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
    $atts = array_merge(array(
        'columns' => $columns,
        'orderby' => $order_by,
        'order' => $sort_by,//rating , population , price high to low ,....
        'rows' => $rows,
        'page' => $i,
    ));
    $shortcode = new WC_Shortcode_Products($atts, 'recent_products');
    echo $shortcode->get_content();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this codefor arg

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'orderby'   => $args = array(
                'filter[limit]' => 6,
                'filter[category]' => $category,
                'filter[orderby]' => 'meta_value_num',
                'filter[order]' => 'DESC',
                'filter[orderby_meta_key]' => '_wc_average_rating'
            ),
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                    'field'     => 'id',
                    'terms'     => $category
                )
            ),
            'posts_per_page' => $product_number
        );
```